# Pillow - Resizing a GIF

Tags: python, image-processing, gif, python-imaging-library

I have a `gif` that I would like to resize with `pillow` so that its size decreases. The current size of the `gif` is 2MB.

I am trying to

1. resize it so its height / width is smaller
2. decrease its quality.

With JPEG, the following piece of code is usually enough so that large image drastically decrease in size.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("my_picture.jpg")
im = im.resize((im.size[0] // 2, im.size[1] // 2), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # decreases width and height of the image
im.save("out.jpg", optimize=True, quality=85)  # decreases its quality
```

With a GIF, though, it does not seem to work. The following piece of code even makes the `out.gif` bigger than the initial gif:

```
im = Image.open("my_gif.gif")
im.seek(im.tell() + 1)  # loads all frames
im.save("out.gif", save_all=True, optimize=True, quality=10)  # should decrease its quality

print(os.stat("my_gif.gif").st_size)  # 2096558 bytes / roughly 2MB
print(os.stat("out.gif").st_size)  # 7536404 bytes / roughly 7.5MB
```

If I add the following line, then only the first frame of the GIF is saved, instead of all of its frame.

```
im = im.resize((im.size[0] // 2, im.size[1] // 2), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # should decrease its size
```

I've been thinking about calling `resize()` on `im.seek()` or `im.tell()` but neither of these methods return an Image object, and therefore I cannot call `resize()` on their output.

Would you know how I can use Pillow to decrease the size of my GIF while keeping all of its frames?

[edit] Partial solution:

Following [Old Bear's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41755454/2564199), I have done the following changes:

- I am using [BigglesZX's script](https://gist.github.com/BigglesZX/4016539) to extract all frames. It is useful to note that this is a Python 2 script, and my project is written in Python 3 (I did mention that detail initially, but it was edited out by the Stack Overflow Community). Running `2to3 -w gifextract.py` makes that script compatible with Python 3.
- I have been resicing each frame individually: `frame.resize((frame.size[0] // 2, frame.size[1] // 2), Image.ANTIALIAS)`
- I've been saving all the frames together: `img.save("out.gif", save_all=True, optimize=True)`.

The new gif is now saved and works, but there is 2 main problems :

- I am not sure that the resize method works, as `out.gif` is still 7.5MB. The initial gif was 2MB.
- The gif speed is increased and the gif does not loop. It stops after its first run.

Example:

original gif `my_gif.gif`:

[image: Original gif]

Gif after processing (`out.gif`) https://i.imgur.com/zDO4cE4.mp4 (I could not add it to Stack Overflow ). Imgur made it slower (and converted it to mp4). When I open the gif file from my computer, the entire gif lasts about 1.5 seconds.

Comment: can you upload the GIF file you are trying to resize?

Comment: @JeruLuke I have added the GIF file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [BigglesZX's script](https://gist.github.com/BigglesZX/4016539), I have created a new script which resizes a GIF using Pillow.

Original GIF (2.1 MB):

[image: Original gif]

Output GIF after resizing (1.7 MB):

[image: Output gif]

I have saved the script [here](https://gist.github.com/PaulineLc/46bb8ddec8a1c3279c24482ae48a1e06). It is using the `thumbnail` method of Pillow rather than the `resize` method as I found the `resize` method did not work.

The is not perfect so feel free to fork and improve it. Here are a few unresolved issues:

- While the GIF displays just fine when hosted by imgur, there is a speed issue when I open it from my computer where the entire GIF only take 1.5 seconds.
- Likewise, while imgur seems to make up for the speed problem, the GIF wouldn't display correctly when I tried to upload it to `stack.imgur`. Only the first frame was displayed (you can see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DebCV.gif)).

Full code (should the above gist be deleted):

```
def resize_gif(path, save_as=None, resize_to=None):
    """
    Resizes the GIF to a given length:

    Args:
        path: the path to the GIF file
        save_as (optional): Path of the resized gif. If not set, the original gif will be overwritten.
        resize_to (optional): new size of the gif. Format: (int, int). If not set, the original GIF will be resized to
                              half of its size.
    """
    all_frames = extract_and_resize_frames(path, resize_to)

    if not save_as:
        save_as = path

    if len(all_frames) == 1:
        print("Warning: only 1 frame found")
        all_frames[0].save(save_as, optimize=True)
    else:
        all_frames[0].save(save_as, optimize=True, save_all=True, append_images=all_frames[1:], loop=1000)


def analyseImage(path):
    """
    Pre-process pass over the image to determine the mode (full or additive).
    Necessary as assessing single frames isn't reliable. Need to know the mode
    before processing all frames.
    """
    im = Image.open(path)
    results = {
        'size': im.size,
        'mode': 'full',
    }
    try:
        while True:
            if im.tile:
                tile = im.tile[0]
                update_region = tile[1]
                update_region_dimensions = update_region[2:]
                if update_region_dimensions != im.size:
                    results['mode'] = 'partial'
                    break
            im.seek(im.tell() + 1)
    except EOFError:
        pass
    return results


def extract_and_resize_frames(path, resize_to=None):
    """
    Iterate the GIF, extracting each frame and resizing them

    Returns:
        An array of all frames
    """
    mode = analyseImage(path)['mode']

    im = Image.open(path)

    if not resize_to:
        resize_to = (im.size[0] // 2, im.size[1] // 2)

    i = 0
    p = im.getpalette()
    last_frame = im.convert('RGBA')

    all_frames = []

    try:
        while True:
            # print("saving %s (%s) frame %d, %s %s" % (path, mode, i, im.size, im.tile))

            '''
            If the GIF uses local colour tables, each frame will have its own palette.
            If not, we need to apply the global palette to the new frame.
            '''
            if not im.getpalette():
                im.putpalette(p)

            new_frame = Image.new('RGBA', im.size)

            '''
            Is this file a "partial"-mode GIF where frames update a region of a different size to the entire image?
            If so, we need to construct the new frame by pasting it on top of the preceding frames.
            '''
            if mode == 'partial':
                new_frame.paste(last_frame)

            new_frame.paste(im, (0, 0), im.convert('RGBA'))

            new_frame.thumbnail(resize_to, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            all_frames.append(new_frame)

            i += 1
            last_frame = new_frame
            im.seek(im.tell() + 1)
    except EOFError:
        pass

    return all_frames
```

Comment: For `putpalette`, I added a `try ... / except ValueError pass` to avoid _illegal image mode_. There is [some changes](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/commit/dba38912fb1217bad9610f842c9ff5194f64ef53) since Pillow 6. Not sure if it's the best way.

Answer (score 5):

According to Pillow 4.0x, the Image.resize function only works on a single image/frame.

To achieve what you want, I believe you have to first extract every frame from the .gif file, resize each frame one at a time and then reassemble them up again.

To do the first step, there appears to be some detail that needs to be attended to. E.g. whether each gif frame uses a local palette or a global palette is applied over all frames, and whether gif replace each image using a full or partial frame. [BigglesZX](https://gist.github.com/BigglesZX/4016539) has developed a script to address these issues while extracting every frame from a gif file so leverage on that.

Next, you have to write the scripts to resize each of the extracted frame and assemble them all as a new .gif using the PIL.Image.resize() and PIL.Image.save().

I noticed you wrote "`im.seek(im.tell() + 1) # load all frames`". I think this is incorrect. Rather it is use to increment between frames of a .gif file. I noticed you used quality=10 in your save function for your .gif file. I did not find this as provided in the [PIL documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#saving). You can learn more about the tile attribute mentioned in BiggleZX's script by reading this [link](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/writing-your-own-file-decoder.html#the-tile-attribute)

Comment: You are right for `quality`, it is a valid argument for `jpg` files but not for `gif` files. I had forgotten to remove it when I tried to change my code from resizing a `gif` to resizing a `jpg`. I have edited my post to reply to the other elements of your answer as I did not have enough space to reply as a comment.

Comment: @Pauline if you compare the size of the individual extracted frame to the  equivalent resized frame, did you find the size of the resized frame smaller? If it is smaller, I think this means the resize function works and the increase in file size is from the recompilation process.  For your looping issue, there is a "looping" option mentioned in the Image.save command that could address your issue. As to the speed, I think the "duration" option controls that. You can see it via the link given in my answer previously.

Comment: Another thought. If there is size increase in reducing your file size, could that be caused by your filter type. See http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/handbook/concepts.html#filters. I noticed you are using Image.ANTIALIAS filter, but did not find it as one of the listed filters for resizing. The Hamming filter looks attractive.

Comment: I found that the `resize` method did not work, and therefore I have switched to `thumbnail` which works. I don't know why `resize` didn't work. I am now using the looping attribute but initially I wanted an infinite loop rather than a fixed number of loops. I did not find a way to achieve this, though, so I set the number of loops to 1000 (it only adds a few bytes to the total size of the `GIF`. I haven't found a solution for the speed which wouldn't require me to manually enter the speed. Ideally I would read the speed from the original `GIF` but haven't found a way to achieve this.

Comment: `Image.ANTIALIAS` is legacy (see [this release note](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/releasenotes/2.7.0.html)) however it is still possible to use it in newer versions of pillow as it is linked to `LANCZOS`. Since using `LANCZOS` in older version of `pillow` would raise an exception, and since using `ANTIALIAS` achieves similar results as using `LANCZOS`, I found it may be better to leave it as `ANTIALIAS`, but I may be wrong, and I'll be happy to be corrected. Thank you for your help, I have found a way to make it work now, and posted it as an answer.

Comment: @Pauline Glad you reached your objective and glad to have been a part of your journey. Noted on the ANTIALIAS. Came across [PIL docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/releasenotes/3.4.0.html?highlight=BOX%20%20filter#new-resizing-filters) recommendation of the BOX filter for scaling down for certain scale.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the function below to resize and crop images including animated ones (GIF, WEBP) Simply, we need to iterate each frame in the gif or webp.

```
from math import floor, fabs
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

def transform_image(original_img, crop_w, crop_h):
  """
  Resizes and crops the image to the specified crop_w and crop_h if necessary.
  Works with multi frame gif and webp images also.

  args:
  original_img is the image instance created by pillow ( Image.open(filepath) )
  crop_w is the width in pixels for the image that will be resized and cropped
  crop_h is the height in pixels for the image that will be resized and cropped

  returns:
  Instance of an Image or list of frames which they are instances of an Image individually
  """
  img_w, img_h = (original_img.size[0], original_img.size[1])
  n_frames = getattr(original_img, 'n_frames', 1)

  def transform_frame(frame):
    """
    Resizes and crops the individual frame in the image.
    """
    # resize the image to the specified height if crop_w is null in the recipe
    if crop_w is None:
      if crop_h == img_h:
        return frame
      new_w = floor(img_w * crop_h / img_h)
      new_h = crop_h
      return frame.resize((new_w, new_h))

    # return the original image if crop size is equal to img size
    if crop_w == img_w and crop_h == img_h:
      return frame

    # first resize to get most visible area of the image and then crop
    w_diff = fabs(crop_w - img_w)
    h_diff = fabs(crop_h - img_h)
    enlarge_image = True if crop_w > img_w or crop_h > img_h else False
    shrink_image = True if crop_w < img_w or crop_h < img_h else False

    if enlarge_image is True:
      new_w = floor(crop_h * img_w / img_h) if h_diff > w_diff else crop_w
      new_h = floor(crop_w * img_h / img_w) if h_diff < w_diff else crop_h

    if shrink_image is True:
      new_w = crop_w if h_diff > w_diff else floor(crop_h * img_w / img_h)
      new_h = crop_h if h_diff < w_diff else floor(crop_w * img_h / img_w)

    left = (new_w - crop_w) // 2
    right = left + crop_w
    top = (new_h - crop_h) // 2
    bottom = top + crop_h

    return frame.resize((new_w, new_h)).crop((left, top, right, bottom))

  # single frame image
  if n_frames == 1:
    return transform_frame(original_img)
  # in the case of a multiframe image
  else:
    frames = []
    for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(original_img):
      frames.append( transform_frame(frame) )
    return frames
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [a simple code](https://gist.github.com/brvoisin/1ece9083b661bb67bb9d235546b1960a) that resize Gif with the same speed and background transparency. I think it could be helpful.

````
"""
# Resize an animated GIF
Inspired from https://gist.github.com/skywodd/8b68bd9c7af048afcedcea3fb1807966
Useful links:
    * https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#saving
    * https://stackoverflow.com/a/69850807
Example:
    ```
    python resize_gif.py input.gif output.gif 400,300
    ```
"""

import sys

from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageSequence


def resize_gif(input_path, output_path, max_size):
    input_image = Image.open(input_path)
    frames = list(_thumbnail_frames(input_image))
    output_image = frames[0]
    output_image.save(
        output_path,
        save_all=True,
        append_images=frames[1:],
        disposal=input_image.disposal_method,
        **input_image.info,
    )


def _thumbnail_frames(image):
    for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(image):
        new_frame = frame.copy()
        new_frame.thumbnail(max_size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        yield new_frame


if __name__ == "__main__":
    max_size = [int(px) for px in sys.argv[3].split(",")]  # "150,100" -> (150, 100)
    resize_gif(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], max_size)
````

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the script given in the chosen answer but as Pauline commented, it had some problems such as speed issue.

The problem was that the speed wasn't given when saving the new gif. To solve that you must take the speed from the original gif and pass it to the new one when saving it.

Here is my script:

```
from PIL import Image


def scale_gif(path, scale, new_path=None):
    gif = Image.open(path)
    if not new_path:
        new_path = path
    old_gif_information = {
        'loop': bool(gif.info.get('loop', 1)),
        'duration': gif.info.get('duration', 40),
        'background': gif.info.get('background', 223),
        'extension': gif.info.get('extension', (b'NETSCAPE2.0')),
        'transparency': gif.info.get('transparency', 223)
    }
    new_frames = get_new_frames(gif, scale)
    save_new_gif(new_frames, old_gif_information, new_path)

def get_new_frames(gif, scale):
    new_frames = []
    actual_frames = gif.n_frames
    for frame in range(actual_frames):
        gif.seek(frame)
        new_frame = Image.new('RGBA', gif.size)
        new_frame.paste(gif)
        new_frame.thumbnail(scale, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        new_frames.append(new_frame)
    return new_frames

def save_new_gif(new_frames, old_gif_information, new_path):
    new_frames[0].save(new_path,
                       save_all = True,
                       append_images = new_frames[1:],
                       duration = old_gif_information['duration'],
                       loop = old_gif_information['loop'],
                       background = old_gif_information['background'],
                       extension = old_gif_information['extension'] ,
                       transparency = old_gif_information['transparency'])
```

Also I noticed that you must save the new gif using `new_frames[0]` instead of creating a new Image Pillow's object to avoid adding a black frame to the gif.

If you want to see a test using pytest on this script you can check  [my GitHub's repo](https://github.com/Alejandroacho/ScaleGif).